# HTML5: How to play sound on every mobile device

Tags: html, web-applications, audio, mobile

I was wondering how to play sound on every mobile device.

- iPhone/iPad
- Android
- Windows Phone 7
- Windows Phone <= 6.5
- Symbian
- Blackberry
- Bada

This should work as a Webapp (HTML).

Answer (score 1):

This is how you implement HTML5 audio into your page for every device:

```
<audio controls preload>
    <source src="path/to/file.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
    <source src="path/to/file.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
    <!--
    Here comes the Flash (in case you want any) fallback,
    or you can write something here like this
    -->
    <p class="error-message">Try another browser...</p>
</audio>
```

If you are trying to use it via SSL, it's not gonna work, read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10089632/819194
This is what we have figured and how we have solved our stuff.

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Bada, but avoiding Flash and instead using JavaScript or server-side browser/device detection to serve either **.mp3** or **.ogg** files should cover most bases.

Comment: Yea, f*ck, that's hard to achieve. Some people say you should use AAC, but on my Android devices (SG Note, Acer Iconia A500) there is no support for AAC.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942365/html5-audio-wont-play-on-mobile-devices/9942865#9942865