# HTML5 Audio doesn't work for mobile

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, html

I have an issue that has been confronting me for a bit, and thorough research has not yielded an answer. I have a jukebox on my site. The final html output looks like:

```
    <body>
        <audio id='a1' controls autoplay oncontextmenu='return false;' onended='ender()'>
            <source src='/serve.php?id=sqm1&token=532fbcd1363da23e72cbcf1ae0827aec&codec=mp3&pretrack' type='audio/mp3'>
        </audio>
        <script>
            var link1 = '/jukebox.php?jukebox=on&track=3'; var link2 = '/jukebox.php?jukebox=on&track=20'; var link3 = '/jukebox.php?jukebox=on&track=2';
        </script>
        <div id='music'>

            <button class='btn btn-primary btn_prev' onclick='gotolink("/jukebox.php?jukebox=on&track=20")'>Previous</button>

            <button class='btn btn-primary btn_next' onclick='gotolink("/jukebox.php?jukebox=on&track=3")'>Next</button>
            <br><br>
             Repeat: <input type='checkbox' id='repeat'>
        </div>
        </div>
   </body>
```

The way it works is that the page generates a random token (first checking that it is indeed a new token), and inserts that into a database. The serve.php validates the token and ensures it hasn't been used before. It then outputs the contents of the audio file along with some headers. If it makes a difference, this is served over SSL/TLS. The buttons make use AJAX to mitigate the need for full page reloads. Ender() simply makes an AJAX request for the next piece of music.

This is where it gets weird - this works great on desktop, but it doesn't work at all on mobile. Even if the user clicks the play button on their device it doesn't work. I also see that the time displays as 0:00 / 0:00.

Any help on solving this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: did you look here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942365/html5-audio-wont-play-on-mobile-devices

Comment: I have - I was hoping that the issue wasn't SSL, as my entire website is secured with it. This was the closest thing I saw that resembled my issue, but it mentions that older versions of the OSes suffer, and I am using nearly the newest version.

Comment: What mobile browsers, are in question?

Comment: Android (stock and Chrome) and IOS are the ones I've tested so far.